# log4j2 generates folder with older date - Springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am using log4j2 for logging in my springboot project. I am deploying my application on IBM WebSphere.

I can see logs, the date and time are correct. I checked the web server logs as well, datetime is correct.

The folder generated by log4j has a date which is 1 day before. For example, right now it generated a folder with 2019-05-08 while it's 9th today.

I have used

```
<Property name="logRolledDirectoryPath">/path/to/logs/%date{yyyy-MM-dd}</Property>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

It re-creates file (and folder) when file needs to be rolled over. What is the rollover policy? If it is size based then it will continue use initial file name until size reaches limit.

Comment: the issue is not with the file name, I create folders and then I generate logs in them. The date of log files is correct but the folder date is day before the actual date. I am using time based, 11 pm daily and size as well which is 25 MB

Comment: So at 11 pm it creates new file name and sets yesterday date to folder.

Comment: Exactly so folder date is 8 and it has log files of 9, similarly folder of 7th date has log files of 8th

Comment: `logRolledDirectoryPath` is not standard property. Can you add policies and appender configs to question?

Comment: I fixed it, it works fine with `%${date:yyyy-MM-dd}` instead of `%date{yyyy-MM-dd}`

Comment: I assume `%date` syntax resolves variable at start up time, while `%${date}` injects variable placeholder to file name pattern and it is resolved during rollover

Comment: My other suggestion would be to give up `logRolledDirectoryPath` variable and add `%date` directly to file name pattern of `RollingFileAppender`

Comment: it was `$${date:yyyy-MM-dd}` , it didn't work... `${date:yyyy-MM-dd}` worked fine... I didn't add %...typo it was

Comment: actually using the same variable for 4 profiles so have declared it globally

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you are doing rollover at 11PM, so you're creating the folder one hour before the next day. so it makes sense that most of the logs in the folder will belong to the next day

Comment: but at the time of creation, the logs have the date of current date and the folder name should have the same date since I am using %d{yyyy-MM-dd}\

Comment: current log files are saved in the folder at the time of generation